# Can ( and how ) I deploy a Nuxt.js app like a Web Component like you can with Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

So when building a vue app you can set the target as a web component and then embed this in your website.

Is there a similar way for Nuxt.js to build the app as a Web Component?

Comment: I don't think it makes sense for a Nuxt application to be embedded as a Web Component. One of the main selling-points for Nuxt is it's an easy implementation of SSR. This requires Nuxt to be running on the server side of things, which basically means it cannot be embedded into a static website. Using Nuxt without SSR, is basically just an opinionated way to write a Vue application - with auto-generated routes - and then I don't think there's any reason to use Nuxt at all. For that reason, even if you COULD do it with Nuxt, I don't think I would want to.

Comment: Thanks Nikolaj - fortunately I haven't gone far with the app so I can easily migrate to Vue.